# Attributes to multiple fields

Tags: attributes, vala

Is it possible add one attribute for multiple fields ?

For instance:

```
public class MainWindow : ApplicationWindow {
    [GtkChild]
    private GtkScale in_amp_scale;
    private GtkScale in_stereo_scale;
    private HVMeter inmeter_l;
    private HVMeter inmeter_r;
    // ...
}
```

In that case apply the `GtkChild` attribute to every field below it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Vala dev here). No it's no possible. You have to put the attribute on every field.